# Daily import .csv files from sftp to a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I'm trying to automate a simple and daily task: There're multiple .csv files on a SFTP-server that I want to import in a MySQL-database.

The filenames have a structure like 20160601-1.csv, 20160601-2.csv, 20160601-3.csv, etc. The number of files divers from 8 to 20 per day. The layout of the .csv is always the same (10 columns with some empty fields).

I know this isn't very detailed, but i'm searching for some hours now and I don't know where to begin.

I think php is a good way to do this? Or maybe Python?

Comment: The language doesn't matter here. You probably can achieve that in any of them. Do you need to process these files before you put hte data into DB or are you able to use simply `LOAD DATA INFILE ...` in MySQL? If so, you probably can do that in simple bash script.

Comment: @dragoste: If doing it from a shell, I'd prefer the mysqlimport utility over `LOAD DATA`.  But otherwise I agree with everything you just said.

Comment: @dragoste It is a tab separated file and i need to ignore the first 5 lines. My experience with tab separated files is that empty fields sometimes causes some trouble with LOAD DATA and LOAD DATA INFILE (because of trailing I think?) so I replace all tabs (/t) with comma's en import the csv to mysql. But if there's an option to import in directly that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in PHP using fgetcsv() function,

Sample code to read csv file

```
    //read file
        $fp = fopen($filename,'r') or die("can't open file");
        $csv_line=fgetcsv($fp);
        $last=0;

        $insert_count=0;
        while($csv_line = fgetcsv($fp,1024))
        {
             //$csv_line is an indexed array for values on each line
             //database update code goes here
        }
```

Comment: It's worth to note that it will execute separate query for each row. For large files that will take a long time to handle. It may be better to do batch inserts, e.g. every 100 or 1000 rows.

Comment: You can insert multiple rows in single query like `INSERT INTO tbl_name
    (a,b,c) VALUES  (1,2,3),  (4,5,6),  (7,8,9);`

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I meant.